# I do not understand how keyword NEW in Java was used here

Tags: java

I'm new to java, but my understanding is that the keyword `new` comes before a constructor. However, in this example from Oracle's Java Tutorial, this is not the case.

```
public static int numSuits = 4;
public static int numRanks = 13;
public static int numCards = numSuits * numRanks;

private Card[][] cards;

public Deck() {
    cards = new Card[numSuits][numRanks];
    for (int suit = Card.DIAMONDS; suit <= Card.SPADES; suit++) {
        for (int rank = Card.ACE; rank <= Card.KING; rank++) {
            cards[suit-1][rank-1] = new Card(rank, suit);
        }
    }
}
```

Card is class, and I do not understand what this line means:

```
cards = new Card[numSuits][numRanks];
```

Can someone please explain what this line of code means.

Comment: It's a way to initialize an array

Comment: It is >>a<< way to initialize an array.  There is another way that doesn't use the `new` keyword.  Perhaps that is what is confusing I.D.

Comment: @StephenC I rather doubt that someone who doesn't know Java arrays is being confused by the reflective instantiation option.

Comment: @chrylis What about `int[][] a = {{1,2}, {3,4}};` ?

Comment: @chrylis - What Erwin says ...

Comment: @StephenC Ah, I read "initialize" and thought "instantiate".

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `new Card[numSuits][numRanks]` is instantiating a 2 dimensional array of cards, not the Card class itself.  Instantiating the Card class comes later, inside of the 2 for loops as `new Card(rank, suit);`